# Merging pandas DataFrames without changing the original column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I want to combine 2 dataframes with some conditions. I think I need aggregated features from both pd.merge and pd.concat, I read through all the examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) but still didn't find info to solve my problem.

left:

```
key1  key2  valueX  valueY
 A    a1     1       4
 B    b1     2       5
 C    c1     3       6
```

right:

```
key1  key2  valueX  valueY
 A    a1     7       10
 B    b2     8       11
 C    c1     9       12
```

I want to combine them so it's

- merged on 2 keys on axis=1
- outer join
- keep the ValueX, valueY names unchanged, just append new columns to the right with the same column names

like below:

```
    key1  key2  valueX  valueY  valueX  valueY
     A    a1     1       4       7       10
     B    b1     2       5      nan      nan
     B    b2    nan     nan      8       11
     C    c1     3       6       9       12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perform a FULL OUTER JOIN with `merge`, and remove the suffixes afterward.

```
u = left.merge(right, on=['key1', 'key2'], suffixes=('', '__2'), how='outer') 
u.columns = u.columns.str.replace('__2', '')

u
  key1 key2  valueX  valueY  valueX  valueY
0    A   a1     1.0     4.0     7.0    10.0
1    B   b1     2.0     5.0     NaN     NaN
2    C   c1     3.0     6.0     9.0    12.0
3    B   b2     NaN     NaN     8.0    11.0
```

Comment: Nice...simple and straightforward.... it solves my problem! =)  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want duplicate `columns` , but you can using `concat`

```
Newdf=pd.concat([df1.set_index(['key1',  'key2']),df2.set_index(['key1',  'key2'] )],axis=1).\
        reset_index()
Newdf
Out[711]: 
  key1 key2  valueX  valueY  valueX  valueY
0    A   a1     1.0     4.0     7.0    10.0
1    B   b1     2.0     5.0     NaN     NaN
2    B   b2     NaN     NaN     8.0    11.0
3    C   c1     3.0     6.0     9.0    12.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! but it seems to re-order my keys so I accepted another answer, but thank you for the inspiration, I didn't know I can set multiple indexes before... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can merge with space as suffix and strip later

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on = ['key1', 'key2'], suffixes=(' ', ' '), how = 'outer')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.str.strip()

    key1    key2    valueX  valueY  valueX  valueY
0   A       a1      1.0     4.0     7.0     10.0
1   B       b1      2.0     5.0     NaN     NaN
2   C       c1      3.0     6.0     9.0     12.0
3   B       b2      NaN     NaN     8.0     11.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! =)